# C++Builder 10.3 app won't run on a new PC

Tags: c++builder-10.3-rio

I got a new laptop (HP Omen) running Windows 10 Home 64bit. I put my 32bit C++Builder app on the new laptop, and it doesn't run.

I can see in Task Manager that the app starts to load, but within 2-3 seconds it is removed from Task Manager, and the program does not run.

I see the mouse pointer change to an hourglass for 2 seconds, but that is it!

I tried running in safe mode, running as admin, running from a command prompt.

There is no antivirus installed. I disabled Microsoft Defender.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it's impossible to say anything about that, but the usual first steps is to check the required runtimes and any other requirement by your program, like other dependant libraries, permissions data files and the like.

Comment: The fact that the app runs for 2-3 seconds at all, and it is changing the mouse cursor, means it IS running, it is just exiting shortly afterwards. Maybe it is throwing an uncaught exception, for instance. Or maybe it is closing its MainForm window before you can see it. There are many possibilities. The fact that the mouse cursor is changing suggests the app is trying to load something at runtime, maybe from a database or other external resource, that is likely failing. Most apps don't change the mouse cursor during their startup.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know what code to post in a 100,000 line program. I'll put some ShowMessage() in the constructors and see if I can pinpoint where it is stopping.